# What do we call a person who never spells words right?

Tags: single-word-requests

Please tell me one word for persons who always misspell.

Comment: Please read the guidelines that are included in the tag `single-word-requests` Your question is off topic because it lacks a sample sentence, you do not tell us if you want a formal or informal expression, if the word should be commonly known or not.

Comment: You also need to say whether you want a noun ("The person is a poor speller") or an adjective ("The person is illiterate").

Answer (score 2):

[Cacography](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cacography) means bad at spellings or writing. So, the person who is bad at spellings or writing is called Cacographer.

Unfortunately, this word is an [archaic word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/archaic-words/). So, its usage is very limited.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *always* ... of course they will spell words right. The most well-known condition is [dyslexia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyslexia) (which, ironically, itself is a hard word to spell correctly) and the word *dyslexic* can be used as an adjective or noun for the people who suffer from it.

> Dyslexia, also known as reading disorder, is characterized by trouble with reading despite normal intelligence. Different people are affected to varying degrees. Problems may include difficulties in **spelling words**, reading quickly, writing words, "sounding out" words in the head, pronouncing words when reading aloud and understanding what one reads.

<sub>(from the linked Wikipedia article, emphasis mine)</sub>

Not everybody with spelling troubles is (a) dyslexic, but it's so frequent that people often refer to it that way, e.g. "This article contains so many spelling errors, it must have been written by a dyslexic."

Comment: @JamesRandom Given that the OP seems to be looking for a word to denote a person whose spelling is bad, rather than a condition which *may* cause their spelling to be bad... this might be a good answer to a different question, but it doesn't answer *this* one well.

Comment: Dyslexic seems like a good answer to me